# How to auto refresh weather forecast in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add auto refresh to this block of code can someone correct this for me please need to roundup this project thanks in advance
this is the code I get so far

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    getLocation();

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {

        var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&sensor=true";
        //var url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=43.428852, -80.472206&sensor=true";
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.get(url, function(data, status) {
                //console.log(data)

                if (data == null) {
                    alert("")
                } else {
                    var city = data.results[2].formatted_address;
                    document.getElementById("cityname").innerHTML = city;

                    var country = "cd";
                    var url2 = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22" + city + "%2C%2" + country + "l%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
                    $(document).ready(function() {

                        $.get(url2, function(data, status) {

                            if (data == null) {
                                alert("Error, No Weather Report in this location")

                            } else {
                                //console.log(data)
                                var results = data.query.results;
                                if (results == null) {
                                    alert("Error, No Weather Report in this location")
                                } else {
                                    var location = data.query.results.channel.location;
                                    var forecasts = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast;
                                    var code = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.code;

                                    if (code >= 3 && code <= 16) {
                                        //rain
                                        document.getElementById("myimage").src = "images/rain.png";
                                    } else if (code >= 26 && code <= 30) {
                                        //cloudy
                                        document.getElementById("myimage").src = "images/clouds.png";
                                    } else if (code >= 31 && code <= 32) {
                                        //sun
                                        document.getElementById("myimage").src = "images/sun.png";
                                    } else if (code >= 33 && code <= 34) {
                                        //fair
                                        document.getElementById("myimage").src = "images/forecast.png";
                                    } else {
                                        //Nill
                                    }
                                    document.getElementById("myweathertext").innerHTML = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.text;
                                    document.getElementById("weathernow").innerHTML = toCelsius(data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp) + "°<span>C<span>";
                                    setInverval(getLocation, 6000);
                                    //console.log(toCelsius(data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp));

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: how can I make this javascript  auto refresh weather forecast every 6s

Comment: which part of the block of code will I put the code

Answer (score 2):

Your description is a bit confusing but from what I understand you are trying to run your getLocation() function every 6 seconds. If that is the case, then instead of just calling getLocation() one time in the $(document).ready() function, also call setInterval() with your function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  getLocation();
  setInterval(getLocation(), 6000);
}
```

You should also remove the call to setInterval() from the getLocation() function as it will set the function to call its self every 6 seconds every time it runs.

Comment: I want the weather forecast to refresh itself every 6 seconds

Comment: Ken... in JavaScript it's like `setInterval(getLocation, 6000);` also it's good to close the function using `});`